# Plotting high dimensional data using sk-learn in Python3

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm training a spam mail classifier using LinearSVC from sk-learn, which works pretty well.
My implementation :

```
import os
import numpy
from pandas import DataFrame
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, f1_score
from sklearn import svm

# So that we can successfully truncate the headers
# in e-mails
NEWLINE = '\n'

# set variables for convenience
HAM = 'ham'
SPAM = 'spam'

# Sources of all the e-mail files
SOURCES = [
    ('C:/data/spam', SPAM),
    ('C:/data/easy_ham', HAM),
    ('C:/data/hard_ham', HAM),
    # ('C:/data/beck-s', HAM),
    # ('C:/data/farmer-d', HAM),
    # ('C:/data/kaminski-v', HAM),
    # ('C:/data/kitchen-l', HAM),
    # ('C:/data/lokay-m', HAM),
    # ('C:/data/williams-w3', HAM),
    ('C:/data/BG', SPAM),
    # ('C:/data/GP', SPAM),
    # ('C:/data/SH', SPAM)
]

# These 'cmds' files are not e-mail files, so we
# better skip them
SKIP_FILES = {'cmds'}


# path variable contains the path to files
def read_files(path):
    for root, dir_names, file_names in os.walk(path):
        # for all the files, join the path to get absolute path
        for path in dir_names:
            read_files(os.path.join(root, path))
        for file_name in file_names:
            if file_name not in SKIP_FILES:
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
                if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                    # the initial line is irrelevant data (e-mail header), so skip it
                    past_header, lines = False, []
                    # open the file in latin-1, since some of the mail is not unicode
                    f = open(file_path, encoding="latin-1")
                    for line in f:
                        if past_header:
                            lines.append(line)
                        # after the initial line, past_header will be true
                        elif line == NEWLINE:
                            past_header = True
                    f.close()
                    content = NEWLINE.join(lines)
                    yield file_path, content


# uses library called 'Panda' to build dataframe
def build_data_frame(path, classification):
    rows = []
    index = []
    # file_name contains the name of the file
    # and the text contains the actual e-mail
    # look at the above function's last line
    for file_name, text in read_files(path):
        # append the text and it's class,
        # class will be passed to this function
        # as a parameter
        rows.append({'text': text, 'class': classification})
        index.append(file_name)

    # create dataFrame
    data_frame = DataFrame(rows, index=index)
    return data_frame


# Initialise an empty DataFrame
data = DataFrame({'text': [], 'class': []})

# for all the path and classification provided
# in sources, build a dataframe out of it
for path, classification in SOURCES:
    data = data.append(build_data_frame(path, classification))

#  The last thing we do is use DataFrame's reindex to shuffle
#  the whole dataset. Otherwise, we'd have contiguous blocks
#  of examples from each source. This is important for validating
#  prediction accuracy later.
data = data.reindex(numpy.random.permutation(data.index))

pipeline = Pipeline([
    # CountVectorizer vectorizes the input and converts
    # the collection of text documents to matrix of
    # token words.
    # We pass it a n-grams range of minimum 1 and maximum 2
        ('count_vectorizer', CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2))),
    # Use Linear Support Vector Machine
    ('classifier', svm.LinearSVC())
])

k_fold = KFold(n=len(data), n_folds=6)
scores = []
confusion = numpy.array([[0, 0], [0, 0]])
for train_indices, test_indices in k_fold:
    train_text = data.iloc[train_indices]['text'].values
    train_y = data.iloc[train_indices]['class'].values.astype(str)

    test_text = data.iloc[test_indices]['text'].values
    test_y = data.iloc[test_indices]['class'].values.astype(str)

    pipeline.fit(train_text, train_y)
    predictions = pipeline.predict(test_text)

    confusion += confusion_matrix(test_y, predictions)
    score = f1_score(test_y, predictions, pos_label=SPAM)
    scores.append(score)

print('Total emails classified:', len(data))
print('Support Vector Machine Output : ')
print('Score:' + str((sum(scores) / len(scores)) * 100) + '%')
print('Confusion matrix:')
print(confusion)
```

Which has F1 score of 0.992.

So, the next thing I want to do is print the SVM result in following way where every dot is a e-mail :
[image: SVM Result]

But the problem is, my input matrix is high dimensional so I cannot use `matplotlib.pyplot` to print out the result of SVM. So any resources that'll give me a workaround are appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean that your input matrix is high dimensional? Do you mean the number of input features is higher than 2 or 3? or do you mean the number of training examples is too large?

Comment: @ChesterVonWinchester my input email is converted to matrix in the form of [1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1] where every number represents words present/not present so that's what is high dimensional, there are many features, and that's what I want to plot

Comment: One option would be to use a dimensionality reduction technique (sklearn offers many) to reduce the data to 2D. PCA would probably be the first thing to try. Afterwards, you could color code your examples according to the predicted class. Unfortunately, this method is independent of the SVM method, and loses the decision boundary information. For example if your data were 3D, two classes might lie in two planar regions separated by some small distance. SVM would find the separating plane fine, but PCA would collapse everything onto the same plane ...

Comment: ... On the other hand (and this would be unique to a linear method, such as linear SVM), you might be able to cook up something that preserves the decision boundary by projecting your data onto a 2D subspace parallel to the separating hyper plane. This would be interesting, and I've not seen it done before. It might take a bit to work out the mathematics, however!